# ref undefined trying to get input id using createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What's wrong with my code below? I got undefined on `id`

```
export default class ComponentName extends Component {
  myInput = React.createRef()

  handleChange = (event, inputRef) => {
    console.log('id', inputRef.id) //undefined
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          ref={this.myInput}
          id={this.props.id}
        />
        {children && (
          <label
            onClick={e => this.handleChange(e, this.myInput)}
            htmlFor={''}
          >
            {children}
          </label>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `console.log('id', this.inputRef.current.id)`. To be safe

The actual reference to the DOM element is actually present in `current` property of the ref object.

On taking a closer look at the examples in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), we see that the element is referenced by the `.current` property

```
  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }
```

Putting up the example here for convenience

> ```
> class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
>     this.textInput = React.createRef();
>     this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);   }
>
>   focusTextInput() {
>     // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
>     // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
>     this.textInput.current.focus();   }
>
>   render() {
>     // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
>     // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
>     return (
>       <div>
>         <input
>           type="text"
>           ref={this.textInput} />
>
>         <input
>           type="button"
>           value="Focus the text input"
>           onClick={this.focusTextInput}
>         />
>       </div>
>     );   } }
> ```